# How do I specify an alternate/additional package source for `apt-get`?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I need to install an older version of gcc on Ubuntu 10.04 (Beta 2); and I'm told I can install a previous package.  At present, I can't compile version gcc-3.3.x, and I'm looking to install a package.

**How do I instruct `apt-get` to pull stuff from previous Ubuntu archives?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is the file you want.

*However* due to binary compatibility you're likely to have issues going back more the a release or two.

I don't have any Ubuntu machines to hand, but on Debian gcc-3.3 is in Etch (circa Q1 2007 as a legacy compiler), and gcc-3.4 is in Lenny (circa mid-2009 ditto).

If it's C your best bet is to simply install an old system and build on that. If it's C++ you're likely out of luck due to binary compatability changes.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is put together a cross compiler that uses existing libraries in the embedded system.  For compatibility I (think I) need to build a gcc-3.4.5 cross compiler.  But compiling with gcc-4.x fails.

Comment: I've been playing with `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which is creating just as many problems as it is solving.  Nonetheless, you answered the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Binary packages need to have matching (or equivalent) libc versions. So taking a binary package built against libc 2.2 and running it on a system with libc 2.7 isn't going to work.

You could take a **source** package and rebuild it. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Toolchain/Crosscompilers/ARMEABIToolchain) is an outline of what to do for a  GCC corss-compiler for an ARM processor target from Ubuntu, you should be able to adapt that general process.

Another option would be to build GCC C/C++ 3.3.6 from the [original](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) source yourself.

I just [noticed](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lucid-changes/2010-March/009226.html) that it appears that Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx has a package called `gcc-3.3` which should be available for you to install.